# Extracting names in LLVM IR

Tags: variables, llvm, extract

I'm currently writing passes using LLVM and I have a few questions regarding variable/parameter/argument names.

1. Say I have this struct:

   ```
   struct Kid {
       char name[30];
       int age;
       char hobby[30];
   };
   ```

I'm running a module pass and found `Kid`'s corresponding `StructType` in the module. I would like to use the names of `Kid`'s members but I don't know how to access them. I tried using an `element_iterator` but it only returns the members as `Type`. How can I access the names of a struct's data member?

EDIT: The purpose of this is so I can be able to determine whether the member of type 'char' I'm currently dealing with is 'name' or 'hobby', so I can perform a different action in each case. Something like:

```
    case "name" do something;
    case "hobby" do something else;
```

Is there another way to differentiate between to members of the same type?

2. Say I have a function `foo(int a, int b)`.
   How can I get the names of a function's parameters?
   I tried running an `arg_iterator` on a call to `foo` to find the 
   arguments but when I call `getName()` on an argument it returns an empty `StringRef`.

Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

There are no "names of fields" in LLVM IR. In fact, the names of types are intended to be used for debug purposes only, so you should never rely on them. Same for names of the Values used to represent the arguments - they could easily be stripped out.

If you need the source names, then you'd need to rely on debug information.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll edit the question to be more specific about what i want to do.

What about the second question?

Comment: I believe I answered to the second question as well. All the "names" are source-level features, so you don't have them in IR. This is for reason, e.g. otherwise you won't be able to deal with C/C++ unions or bitfields. So, if you need to use source-level things, then you need to perform everything inside a frontend. Or use some other way to recover the necessary information, e.g. debug info.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to edit that comment, I didn't notice that until a certain point.
Thank you!